# Set CaseComment as Private

Tags: apex, trigger, developer

I'm trying to write a new trigger to set update CaseComment as Private if the email was sent to an internal recipient. For some reason, this trigger works on one of my orgs but on my new org I get the following error:

```
Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: AsynchronousFutureMethods at line 23 column 9
```

The Code of the trigger:

```
trigger SetInternalCommentsAsPrivate on CaseComment (before insert, after insert) {

List<Id> privateCaseComment = new List<Id>();

for(Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.size; i++){

    if(Trigger.new[i].CommentBody <> null){
        if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.new[i].CommentBody.startsWith('[Recipients:')){
            String sender = Trigger.new[i].CommentBody.substring('[Recipients:'.length(), Trigger.new[i].CommentBody.indexOf(']', '[Recipients:'.length())).trim();
            if(sender.contains('COMPANY_DOMAIN')){
                privateCaseComment.add(Trigger.new[i].Id);
            }
        }else{
            if(Trigger.IsBefore && Trigger.new[i].CommentBody.startsWith('From:')){
                String sender = Trigger.new[i].CommentBody.substring('From:'.length(), Trigger.new[i].CommentBody.indexOf('\n', 'From:'.length())).trim();
                Trigger.new[i].IsPublished = !(sender.contains('COMPANY_DOMAIN'));
            }
        }
    }
}

if(privateCaseComment.size()>0){
    AsynchronousFutureMethods.setInternalCommentsAsPrivate(privateCaseComment);
}    
}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: can u explain your "AsynchronousFutureMethods" class??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the new org `AsynchronousFutureMethods` class doesn't exist. That's why you are getting complier error.

Deploy this class to your new org taking from other org where this trigger compiled successfully.